# Android start service only when screen is on

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I use an AlarmManager to schedule a service, every hour, but i need only when the screen is unlocked, so the final user is using the device.
I tried to use AlarmManager, with variables SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF but without success.
I can't understand how to set the AlarmManager repeating schedule.

Comment: As far as I know, You can not set the AlarmManager class according to if user is using the device. You can only set the alarm according to time and you must check the device's screen is active or deactive. 

Alternatively you can Wake the screen up when your service starts to work. Using that properties, You will need to acquire a WakeLock in onReceive() before calling startActivity(), and release that WakeLock after the user responds to your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Before running your service, check if Screen is OFF or ON.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( !keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 // Code here.
}
```

Comment: Yes it is useful.
So, I do I start immediately the service, when the screen is turned on?

Comment: do you get response from AlarmManager every hour?

Comment: Yes... I always get response

Comment: Run the service every one hour, using BroadcastReceiver catch if the alarm event has been fired, if the screen is ON that moment do what you need to do.

Comment: I already do this procedure... But, if the user don't "wake up" the device for 3 hours, I must start the service without waiting.

Comment: keep an eye on the time then, count number of hours since the device has been asleep, if the count goes up beyond 3 hours, run the code you intent to, Please post your code, I am a bit confused now.